# RustをVSCodeで作成するときにソースコード管理を無効にしたい

Tags: git, vscode, windows-10, rust

表題の通りなのですが、いつも常にgithub等にコミットしてコーディングするわけではないので、これを無効にしたいです。
ただ普通に編集して保存したいのですが、どうしても気になってしまい集中できません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

28という数字がかかれている所をこのプロジェクトでは無効にしたいです。
(というよりもforkなどで対応している為、正直いりません…)

調べてみましたが、自分のサーチ力では解決できず皆様のお力をお借りしたいです…!
よろしくお願いします!

Comment: 開いているプロジェクトのフォルダに `.git` フォルダは存在しますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そもそも Git でのバージョン管理をしないのであれば， Cargo でプロジェクトをつくるときにそれを無効化することができます (デフォルトでは Git になります)．

cargo init を使っている場合は:

```
cargo init --vcs none
```

cargo new を使っている場合は:

```
cargo new --vcs none [project_name]
```

で可能です．

Comment: おお、その方法があったのですね!!!
ありがとうございます!
非常に助かりました。

Answer (score 1):

VS Code側で特定のプロジェクトのバージョン管理をオフにするなら、以下のようにします。

1. プロジェクトのルートディレクトリー（`Cargo.toml`があるディレクトリー）に、`.vscode`というディレクトリーを作る
2. `.vscode`ディレクトリーに`settings.json`というファイルを作り、以下の内容を書く

```js
{
    "git.enabled": false
}
```

ただ、そのプロジェクトでバージョン管理を全く行わないつもりなら、他の回答のように、CargoでプロジェクトをつくるときにGitでのバージョン管理を無効化する方が良さそうです。

Comment: なるほどですね、このようにも設定できるんですね!
助かります!
あまりないかもですが、後からこれはgitにうっかり上げたらまずいねってとき各々ローカルで編集とかで使えるかもですね(ブランチ切れという感じですが、そういう現場もあるにはあるので)